# Grafana showing 'no data found' only for few Relative time range filter

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-api, grafana-alerts, grafana-loki

Hi I am working on Grafana V7.0.0 with Postgresql as DB, where data is displaying correctly when I select Today/This year(Filters with months/day/year) etc.. But when I select data filter as 
Last 6 hours/ last 12 hours( FILTERS WITH TIME) showing as 'No data to display'.

Note : Grafana time zone displays correct time only If i select UTC, hence tried below 2 solutions still the result is same.
    1. Changed the DB and Host timing to UTC
    2. Changed all the timings to EDT as em pulling data from splunk which is based on EDT time zone.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. For all I know there just could be no entries the last 12 hours. Can you provide a few more details please?

Comment: Data is for full day. For ex. If I see dashboard at 10.pm data till 10.pm is visible when I select Today in Time Range.But when I select last 2 hrs/last 6hrs etc dashboard shows No data to display.

Comment: To simplyfy it. My Postgres DB and Grafana Host is in EDT (UTC-4.00) timezone. But If I set grafana time to EDT time is not displaying properly only when UTC is selected graph shows correct data but fails to show data for last 4/3/2/12/6 hours.

Comment: Please add the [mcve] that shows how to reproduce your problem.